# Error al acceder a un servicio web con SSIS

Tags: webservice, wcf, ssis, wsdl

Estoy tratando de acceder a un Servicio Web para un proyecto pero no logro conectarme. Estoy utilizando la herramienta "Tarea Servicio Web", configuro la conexión (HttpConnection) al wsdl, le introduzco el archivo local (WSDLFile) y pongo a True el apartado de Overwrite. Cuando le doy a descargar el WSDL va bien, el problema es que en la pestaña de Entrada, en Service me carga el servicio, pero no me carga ningún método y automáticamente me salta el siguiente mensaje de error:

> "No se puede encontrar la definición para [..]. Falta la descripción de servicios con el espacio de nombres [..]. Nombre del parámetro: name."

En SoapUI me conecta perfectamente, por lo que tiene que ser algún tipo de configuración o error en SISS. El error al que hace referencia el mensaje tiene algo que ver con el 'namespace'. Dentro del servicio original existe un import que llama a otra URL:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="[..]" location="http://[..].svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

Y en esta URL, a la que llama desde 'location', se encuentra el 'xsd:schema' con sus correspondientes 'xsd:import'.

No sé si esto tiene algo que ver con el problema (lo de realizar tantos imports), pero el servicio web no lo puedo cambiar. Probé con otros servicios web más sencillos y funcionan correctamente. Agradecería si alguien tiene una solución para poder conectarme a este servicio web.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que version de visual studio estás usando?

Comment: La versión del 2008. Concretamente la compatible con SQL Server 2008 R2. Uso esta versión para evitar problemas de incompatibilidad con otros paquetes de SSIS.

Comment: Ahi tienes probablemente el problema,creo que las versiones anteriores a 2012 tienen problemas con algunos servicios.De todas maneras, en lugar de importarlo desde ahi trata de utilizar la herramienta [svcutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe), es posible que tengas mas suerte